# Microsoft Translator gives HTTP Error 400 only with certain strings

Tags: python, urllib2, http-error, microsoft-translator

I am translating a large number of strings and using urllib2 to send requests to the API. My program will run fine, but I always get HTTP Error 400 when translating certain strings in particular. Each request I make is exactly the same, except for the text parameter, so I think it must be the text somehow causing the request to be malformed. Here are two strings that I know of that always cause this error:

> @monaeltahawy hatla2eh fel jym bytmrn wla 3arf en fe 7aga bt7sl :d

and

> @yaratambash ta3aly a3zemek 3l fetar

for example.

I know for certain that it isn't the "@" character causing the error, or the fact that "@" is at the front of the string. The API has processed strings with these attributes just fine before.

It also is not the nonsense words in these strings causing issues, because the API has processed nonsense words fine before as well. It just returns the same string that I sent to it.

Here is the code where the error seems to be coming from:

```
        tweet = tweet.encode("utf-8")
        to = "en" 
        translate_params = { 'text' : tweet, 'to' : to }
        request = urllib2.Request('http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?' + urllib.urlencode(translate_params))
        request.add_header('Authorization', 'Bearer '+ self.access_token)

        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)

        # Removes XML tags to return only the translated text
        response_text = ET.fromstring(response.read())
        response_text = ET.tostring(response_text, encoding = 'utf8', method = 'text')

        return response_text
```

I am running Python 2.7 in Eclipse 4.3.2.

Any insight or suggestions would be very much appreciated.